# Can I change English numbers to Arabic/Persian representations when a control is being rendered?

Tags: c#, wpf

English numbers (12345678) and some other symbols like decimal are different in Persian (۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰) or (۳/۱ instead of 3.1). I want the language to  be optional in my controls.

For example, when I set the TextProperty of a TextBlock to "2345", I want it to be shown both "2345" and "۲۳۴۵", optionally.

Can I change a specific font when controls are being rendered? I mean I override render or some other methods and for example add:

```
if (char=='5')
{
    char='۵';
}
```

or is there any other way?
thanks;

Comment: Maybe the following answer would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643740/c-sharp-wpf-converting-english-numbers-to-arabic-numbers

Comment: Thanks EvAlex, I couldn't understand some of the discussions. I think I need more time studying them.

Answer (score 9):

I use a simple code which i write:

```
private string toPersianNumber(string input)
{
   string[] persian = new string[10] { "۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹" };

   for (int j=0; j<persian.Length; j++)
       input = input.Replace(j.ToString(), persian[j]);

     return input;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here My Code Convert English digit to Persian digits by Extension method :

```
 private static readonly string[] pn = { "۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹" };
    private static readonly string[] en = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

public static string ToPersianNumber(this string strNum)
    {
        string chash = strNum;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            chash = chash.Replace(en[i], pn[i]);
        return chash;
    }
    public static string ToPersianNumber(this int intNum)
    {
        string chash = intNum.ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            chash = chash.Replace(en[i], pn[i]);
        return chash;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo), for example:

```
public static string NumberConvertor(this object o, CultureInfo to)
{
    if (o == null) return "";

    var s = o.ToString();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        s = s.Replace(i.ToString(), to.NumberFormat.NativeDigits[i]);
    }

    return s;
}

// usage example
var myNumber = 0123456789.4;
var converted = myNumber.NumberConvertor(new CultureInfo("fa-IR")); // output: ۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹.۴
```