# How to convert digits in the DateTime to Unicode culture in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, unicode, digits

I have converted datetime value in unicode using following code -

```
CultureInfo cultureMarathi = new CultureInfo("mr-IN");
nextCheckDate=nextCheckupDateTimePicker.Value.ToString("dddd, dd-MMM-yyyy", cultureMarathi);
```

It converts my datetime to "गुरूवार, 26 मे 2016" but the digits are still in roman script. How to convert these digits as per the culture.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but can you check if your font has digits in local script?

Comment: I *think* digit substitution takes place during rendering, not when the string is formatted.  See [How can I display culture-specific native digits instead of Arabic numerals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239729) and [C# WPF Converting english numbers to arabic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643740).

Comment: @jdweng: this question is closed for a reason, don't add answers to the question post please.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CultureInfo cultureMarathi = new CultureInfo("mr-IN");
cultureMarathi.NumberFormat.DigitSubstitution = DigitShapes.NativeNational;
nextCheckDate=nextCheckupDateTimePicker.Value.ToString("dddd, dd-MMM-yyyy", cultureMarathi)
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureMarathi;
```

Comment: Why OP should try that?

Comment: +1 for the `NumberFormat.DigitSubstitution`, but surprisingly, in my test, it *still* shows roman digits...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov because `NumberFormat.DigitSubstitution` is a new knowledge for me... But unfortunately, the OP's native digit does not seem to be supported according to your comment.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov lol... is "sympathy vote" the term for my action? - it is also new knowledge... :) (useful for me)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov O.o... I just knew that...

Comment: I edited code with solution.

Comment: @jdweng I've rolled back you invalid edit of the question - feel free to post another answer to duplicate OR vote this question to be re-opened if you believe that it requires unique answer.

Comment: @jdweng: that is not an appropriate action, don't edit answers into questions.